# FireFox issue when second selector for $x.on('change', y

Tags: jquery, firefox, select

Can any one tell me why this works in chrome but not in FireFox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <form class="Frm">
    <select id="xid">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
    </form>
    <script>
    $('.Frm').on('change', '#xid', function(event){
      alert('test);
    });

    /* // but this one works in FireFox
    $('#xid').on('change',function(event){
      alert('test);
    });
    */
    </script>
</body>
```

If I use $('#xid').on('change',function(event) ... then it works fine.

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/csLAk/1827/

I really need to use $selector.on('change', 'secondselector'

.... Similar questions have been asked about using on change with a select drop down, but that's not the question.  My question is, why doesn't it work in FF when using $selector.on('change', 'secondselector'

Edit: FireFox Browser version 7.1 (thanks to Jason P for pointing out that is could be version related)

Comment: Your fiddle is using 1.7 and not 1.10

Comment: same issue, also doesn't fire in FireFox: $('#test').on('change', '#xid', function(event)...

Comment: If it works fine in FF with jsFiddle but not your page then there must be an error somewhere. What's your console show?

Comment: @mplungjan okay, that explains the fiddle issue (it doesn work in ff there too), but does't explain why it doesn't work in FF

Comment: No.. it's also not working in JSFiddle in FireFox (I've just update the link above).  Works in chrome, not in FF ?

Comment: It works for me in FF 23.0.1, what version are you using?

Comment: ahhhh... FF is 7.0.1 (which is 2 years old), could that be it.  I'm updating now, but surely a 2 year old browser can support the above?

Comment: It's tough to tell. jQuery [supports current verson - 1 for most browsers](http://jquery.com/browser-support/), so there's no guarantee for a browser that old.

Comment: hmm, well it was the version of the browser.  I've updated this and it works, but I've no guarantee users wont be using browsers that are > 2 years old

Comment: You also have no guarantee that users won't be using IE5.5, but we typically don't code for that anymore either.